# Merging json objects with jansson in c

Tags: c, json

I have a problem with merging objects in json. I am using jansson library and plain c language and I am not allowed to use anything else. I have read documentation and Api reference. Link: https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/2.9/ In this case it is suggested to use : int json_object_update(json_t *object, json_t *other). There are 3 different types simple update, update_existing, update_missing. None of them give me result that I need. I am using linux. Here is my code for programm, it also does validation and code for argv and errors is not used in this case:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {



json_error_t error;
json_t *jFile;
json_t *File;
int dFile;
int i;

jFile = json_load_file("test1",0, &error);
if(jFile == NULL)
{
  printf("Error opening test1");
  return(-1);
}
File = json_load_file("test2",0, &error);
if(File == NULL)
{
  printf("Error opening test2");
  return(-1);
}
if( json_object_update_missing(jFile,File) < 0){
return(-1);
}


if( json_dump_file(jFile, "out2.json", JSON_INDENT(3)) < 0){
return(-1);
}


if(!jFile){

printf( "argv[ %d ] = %s\n", i, argv[ i ] );
fprintf(stderr, "error on line: %d column: %d position: %d\n %s\n",
        error.line, error.column,
        error.position, error.text);
}
else{
printf( "argv[ %d ] = %s\n", i, argv[ i ] );
    printf("The loaded JSON file is valid\n"); }
return (0);
}
```

For example if i have this(test1):

```
 {
"radio": {
  "Status" : {
    "tx_freq"               : "1000",
    "rx_freq"               : "1000",
    "atpc_rxmax"            : "101"
   }
}
}
```

and this(test2)

```
 {
"radio": {
  "Status" : {
    "tx_freq"               : "1000",
    "rx_freq"               : "1000",
    "new_one"               : "10"
   }
}
}
```

I want to get

```
    {
"radio": {
  "Status" : {
    "tx_freq"               : "1000",
    "rx_freq"               : "1000",
    "atpc_rxmax"            : "101",
    "new_one"               : "10"
   }
}
}
```

If I execute my programm with any of update variations it will just replace different object values or they will remain the same, but I just want to add them. I am quite new in this. At this point I am stuck and any help provided will help me, even if it means not to use janssson provided Api.

Comment: I do not see you do any error checking as the documentation suggests. Please add your error checking to analyze the problem.

Comment: Hi, I modified the code and added error checking, hope it is right. I have done some research and found out that I should not use update function on whole file, but instead using foreach function from Api to search for keys and objects and work directly with them, but still need help with implementing that :/